# Tensorflow dense gradient explanation?

Tags: tensorflow

I recently implemented a model and when I ran it I received this warning:

```
UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. 
This may consume a large amount of memory.
"Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

With some similar parameter settings (embedding dimensionalities) suddenly the model is ridiculously slow.

1. What does this warning imply? It appears that something I've done has caused all of the gradients to be dense and so backprop is doing dense matrix computations
2. If it's that there is an issue with the model that's causing this, how can I identify it and fix it?

Answer (score 66):

This warning is printed when a sparse [`tf.IndexedSlices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/IndexedSlices) object is implicitly converted to a dense [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor). This typically happens when one op (usually [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather)) backpropagates a sparse gradient, but the op that receives it does not have a specialized gradient function that can handle sparse gradients. As a result, TensorFlow automatically densifies the `tf.IndexedSlices`, which can have a devastating effect on performance if the tensor is large.

To fix this problem, you should try to ensure that the `params` input to `tf.gather()` (or the `params` inputs to [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup)) is a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable). Variables can receive the sparse updates directly, so no conversion is needed. Although `tf.gather()` (and `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`) accept arbitrary tensors as inputs, this may lead to a more complicated backpropagation graph, resulting in implicit conversion.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.  How can I identify which op is causing this?

Comment: The easiest way is to look through your code for `tf.gather()` or `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` invocations, find the tensor `t` that is the `params` (first) argument to either of those ops, and print `t.op`. Generally, you will get the best performance if `t` is a `tf.Variable`, but some ops such as  `tf.concat()` have specializations that make the gradients efficient.

Comment: It appears to be a `boolean_mask` being fed a `reshape`.  This is used in a loss calculation far into the graph after mulitple `reshape`s, `pack`s, `tile`s, `expand_dim`s, `squeeze`s, `batch_matmul`s, etc.  Is there a way to identify which op(s) can't accept sparse gradients?

Comment: I have the same problem. My input to ``tf.gather`` is a ``reshape`` output. How can I convert it to a ``Variable``? Thanks.

Comment: for `embedding_lookup`, is it ok to have `tf.placeholder` as param ? I'm not sure if they fulfill the role of `tf.Variable`

Comment: I'm also seeing this warning with a `boolean_mask` but it's just being fed normal variables--nothing is being reshaped.

Comment: can this error occurs when using images with large dimensions..eg:- 8582*1920

Comment: @yoki did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 28):

A dense Tensor can be thought of like a standard python array. A sparse one can be thought of as a collection of indices and values e.g.

```
# dense
array = ['a', None, None, 'c']

# sparse
array = [(0, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
```

So as you can see if you have a lot of empty entries a sparse array will be much more efficient than a dense one. But if all entries are filled in, dense is far more efficient. In your case somewhere in the tensor flow graph a sparse array is being converted to a dense one of indeterminate size. The warning is just saying it is possible that you can waste a lot of memory like this. But it might not be a problem at all if the sparse array is not too big/already quite dense.

If you want to diagnose it I would advise naming your various tensor objects then it will print exactly which ones are being used in this conversion and you can work out what you might be able to adjust to remove it.

Answer (score 9):

Totally agree with the answer of `mrry`.

Actually I will post another solution for this problem.

You could use [`tf.dynamic_partition()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition) instead of [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to eliminate the warning.

The example code is below:

```py
# Create the cells for the RNN network
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(128)

# Get the output and state from dynamic rnn
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, sequence, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length = seqlen)

# Convert output to a tessor and reshape it
outputs = tf.reshape(tf.pack(output), [-1, lstm.output_size])

# Set partions to 2
num_partitions = 2

# The partitions argument is a tensor which is already fed to a placeholder.
# It is a 1-D tensor with the length of batch_size * max_sequence_length.
# In this partitions tensor, you need to set the last output idx for each seq to 1 and 
# others remain 0, so that the result could be separated to two parts,
# one is the last outputs and the other one is the non-last outputs.
res_out = tf.dynamic_partition(outputs, partitions, num_partitions)

# prediction
preds = tf.matmul(res_out[1], weights) + bias
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: dynamic_partition can be used instead of tf.gather(), what can be used instead of tf.nn.embedding_lookup()?

Comment: I guess this does not really solve the problem, only mute the warning. Because it looks like `tf.dynamic_partition` produces dense gradients?