# Get UserWarning while I use tf.boolean_mask

Tags: tensorflow

I got this UserWarning while using `tf.boolean_mask()`:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:93: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

Once I remove it, the warning msg disappear. I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896823/5793660), but I don't use `tf.gather()` and I am sure I pass the `tf.Variable` and `tf.placeholder` to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`. So how could I fix this problem?

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here, got this error due to tf.boolean_mask(). Looking at the graph, you can see that the boolean_mask function actually includes a call to tf.gather().

Following the suggestion made by AI_ROBOT in [the answer you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892412/tensorflow-dense-gradient-explanation#35896823), that is using dynamic_partition() instead of boolean_mask(), did the trick for me!