# Simpler way to avoid the UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a rnn network structure that looks like following

```
        cells = rnn.MultiRNNCell(
            [self._one_rnn_cell(l + 1) for l in range(self.layers)],
            state_is_tuple=True
        ) if self.layers > 1 else self._one_rnn_cell(1)


        out, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, self.inputs,
                                   dtype=tf.float32, scope="DyRNN")
        out = tf.transpose(out, [1, 0, 2])
        num_time_steps = int(out.get_shape()[0])
        last_state = tf.gather(out, num_time_steps - 1, name="last_lstm_state")
```

Here while I am running the code, I am getting the following warning.

> UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
>     "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

Now I understand why this error is coming. I tried out several ideas and the most common one is the following

[How to deal with UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882401/how-to-deal-with-userwarning-converting-sparse-indexedslices-to-a-dense-tensor)

But the problem is this requires too many variable like

max_length
time_steps
seq_length
n_dim
partitions

this make the code very unreadable. I wanted to know if there is a simpler way I can avoid the problem.

Also if the sequence length remain same across all the batches, can I assume `max_length == time_steps == seq_length` ?

Please help, documentation is very less.