# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})

Tags: python, list, numpy, pycharm

```
history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=40, validation_split=0.1)
```

the line problem was this

Showing error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58682026/edit) your question and add more code and context, and the full error traceback. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is `model`?  It isn't part of any of the tagged packages.  Show the full traceback.

Answer (score 51):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out it was a in the form of a list. I had to convert the fields into a numpy array like:

```
training_padded = np.array(training_padded)
training_labels = np.array(training_labels)
testing_padded = np.array(testing_padded)
testing_labels = np.array(testing_labels)
```

thats it!

Answer (score 17):

So this is happening the the newer version of tensorflow I'm not sure from where but I was on version 2.0.0 and this same thing happened

I'm assuming that you are only converting the X array into a numpy array
But rather try converting 'X' as well as 'y' to numpy array using the dtype as np.uint8

That should resolve the problem

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works perfectly now for my program. It shows that I'm going to downgrade my tensorflow and everything seem to be work

Answer (score 17):

[ValueError in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683211/valueerror-in-tensorflow)

https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/

I tried following code and worked for me:

```
IMG_SIZE = 50

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

y = np.array(y)

history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=40, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: I had to also do y = np.array(y).

Answer (score 10):

In my case the problem was only in y. it was a list. in that case i had to change

y = np.array(y)

Answer (score 2):

VIKI already said a good answer. I am adding more information. It used to crash colab host for me as well, before I added the np.array() wrappers.

```
# Need to call np.array() around pandas dataframes.
# This crashes the colab host from TF attempting a 32GB memory alloc when np.array() wrappers are not used around pandas dataframes.
# Wrapping also cures warning about "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input"
history = model.fit(x=np.array(tr_X), y=np.array(tr_Y), epochs=3, validation_data=(np.array(va_X), np.array(va_Y)), batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=spe, validation_freq=5)
```

Crashing host due to out of memory problem has something to do with this:

[Tensorflow dense gradient explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892412/tensorflow-dense-gradient-explanation)

Answer (score 2):

For those who encounter this issue:

Check the type before you throw your data into the model.
For example, it should be

```
print(type(X)) 
# numpy.ndarray
```

Instead of

```
print(type(X))
# list
```

Simply transform the X by

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mahmud's answer fixes the TensorFlow Tutorial "Basic regression: Predict fuel efficiency" error in section [30]. These are the 2 lines:

Change this:

```
example_batch = normed_train_data[:10]
example_result = model.predict(example_batch)
```

To this:

```
example_batch = np.array(normed_train_data[0:10]) 
example_result = model.predict(example_batch)
```

Thanks Mahmud

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert X and y like this:

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 50, 50, 1)
```

and for y

```
y=np.array(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type cast the arrays.

for example:

```
import numpy as np
features = np.array(features,dtype='float64')
labels = np.array(labels, dtype ='float64')
```