# How to pass two images directly into siamese neural network?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Basically, I am taking two images as inputs and preprocessing them and passing them as input to the Siamese CNN model.

```
def create_base_network_signet(input_shape):
    seq = Sequential()
    seq.add(Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(11, 11), activation='relu', name='conv1_1', strides=4, input_shape= input_shape, 
                        kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    seq.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-06, axis=1, momentum=0.9))
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(2, 2)))    
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D((2, 2)))
    
    seq.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv2_1', strides=1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    seq.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-06, axis=1, momentum=0.9))
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(2, 2)))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.3))
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    
    seq.add(Conv2D(384, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv3_1', strides=1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
    
    seq.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv3_2', strides=1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))    
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(2, 2)))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.3))# added extra
    seq.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
    seq.add(Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0005), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    seq.add(Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0005), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    seq.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    return seq
```

My aim to pass images is something similar to this below

```
result = model.fit([image1, image2], y = 1, epochs=10)
```

However, I am getting an error
**Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), <class 'int'>**

Comment: pass y as an array

Comment: Can you please convert `y` as an array using `y=np.array(y)` and then fit the model as `result = model.fit([image1, image2], y , epochs=10)` will resolve the above issue. For more details please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682026/).Thank you!